# Moment.js locale change not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm trying to set the Moment.js default locale to match the browser locale in an Angular application.

I have followed the steps for Typescript as stated [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/) in the docs. This is my code in the `main.ts`

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/locale/es';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

moment.locale(navigator.language);

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

`navigator.language` will default to `es` here because the settings of my browser but I've also tried to set it to `es` manually.

Later in my code I tried to `console.log(moment.locale())` and it prints `es` so I though that all was working. Also when I try to get the week days using `moment.weekDaysShort()` I'm getting the names translated to the `es` locale but not in the correct order. The week should start on `Monday` but the first value of `weekDays` is `Sunday`.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The week should start on Monday but the first value of weekDays is Sunday.

That is not what the moment / contributor team thinks.

## Source will set you free

https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/4caa268356434f3ae9b5041985d62a0e8c246c78/locale/es.js#L37

```
weekdays : 'domingo_lunes_martes_miércoles_jueves_viernes_sábado'.split('_'),
weekdaysShort : 'dom._lun._mar._mié._jue._vie._sáb.'.split('_'),
```

Comment: I also thought that. But reviewing the source file I found this at the bottom of the file: `week : { dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week. }`. So after investigating the source for the `weekDay()` function I discover that you can pass it a boolean parameter. If it's `true` like this: `weekDay(true)` it will consider the first day of the week the day specified by the `dow` property.